# Create buttons for navigation

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I am using the Divi theme in Wordpress. I have to create a set of horizontal buttons as navigation menu. As I am using Divi theme, I created a *standard section* with a *text module* and put the following shortcodes in the text module:

```
<p style="text-align: center;">
[button link="http://localhost/res/" type="big" color="green"]Home[/button]
[button link="http://localhost/res/verticals/" type="big" color="green"]Verticals[/button]
[button link="http://localhost/res/why-res-usp/" type="big" color="green"]Why RES - USP[/button]
[button link="http://localhost/res/our-biodata/" type="big" color="green"]Our Bio-data[/button]
[button link="http://localhost/res/locate-us/" type="big" color="green"]Locate Us[/button]
</p>
```

It created a set of five buttons horizontally but they are too close to each other. Now I need to put more spaces in between these buttons. Is their any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the buttons:

```
[button link="http://localhost/res/" type="big" color="green" style="margin-left: 20px"]
```

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work out. These buttons are objects in within one single text module in divi theme.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try
`&nbsp;`
or
`[&nbsp]`
After each `[/button]`

This character is a non breaking white space. You can copy and paste it for multiple amounts of space too. e.g `&nbsp;``&nbsp;``&nbsp;` or `[&nbsp]``[&nbsp]``[&nbsp]`

Comment: I have already tried it, but didn't work out. These buttons are objects in within one single text module. Probably that's why it's not working. It needs some CSS coding. Unfortunately, I don't have much idea in CSS.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the documentation for the theme. Is this Divi theme by elegantthemes? http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/documentation/advanced-design-settings/

Comment: Yes, it is the theme from elegant themes. I tried the documentation. The button object has only two parameters to set - namely color & size and it does not take inline CSS. I also float a question in divi forum but still haven't got any suitable answer.